# Print array with multiple rows combined and display units with mysqli fetch

Tags: php

I'm trying to display a chartJS graph (grouped) with dynamic input (mysqli). To achieve this I want to use a foreach loop to display the units which are selected in the SQL query. I'm able to print all outcome BUT want to select only specific period's (1 Month, 3 Months or 1 Year).

This is the code I have:

```
<?php

    // initialize $saved here
    $units = array();
    $period = array();
    $crawlDate = array();

    $sql = $baseSQL;
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    //$saved = []; - no need of this now
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $units[] = $row["units"];
            $period[] = $row["period"];
            $crawlDate[] = $row["datetime"];

            print_r($row);

            foreach($units as $key => $value){ 
                echo $value. ",";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Not found.";
    }
?>
```

This outputs the following:

```
Array ( [datetime] => 2020-03-13 00:00:00 [countryCode] => US [subscription] => Renewal [period] => 1 Month [proceedsReason] => [orderType] => [units] => 1 ) 1,Array ( [datetime] => 2020-03-13 00:00:00 [countryCode] => US [subscription] => Renewal [period] => 3 Months [proceedsReason] => [orderType] => [units] => 1 ) 1,1,Array ( [datetime] => 2020-03-11 00:00:00 [countryCode] => US [subscription] => New [period] => 1 Month [proceedsReason] => [orderType] => Pay Up Front Intro Offer [units] => 1 ) 1,1,1,Array ( [datetime] => 2020-03-11 00:00:00 [countryCode] => US [subscription] => Renewal [period] => 1 Month [proceedsReason] => [orderType] => [units] => 1 ) 1,1,1,1,
```

How can I display the units of only 3 Months, or only of '3 Months' and 'Renewal'.

Comment: Well check what the `period` column (and/or `subscription`) contains, before you output the record then?

Comment: Change the query to only select what you want to see

Comment: Is it necessary to query 3 times? Hoped to do it in one time.